# Как сделать поочередную загрузку изображений

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть сайт, и на нем есть слайдер картинок. При загрузки страницы фотографии загружаются одновременно(к примеру смотришь первый слайд, а он ещё прогружается и так все изображения). Как сделать так чтобы они загружались поочередно?

Comment: Мне кажется, самым простым способом решения подобной, а в дальнейшем, будущих проблем - это создать при помощи Javascript заглушку с индикацией загрузки страницы. Пока страничка не прогрузиться, не показывать её пользователю вообще. Это самый простой способ. Если заморочиться, то необходимо искать причину такого поведения. Медленный доступ к серверу и т.п. Также можно сделать асинхронную загрузку изображений.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот примерно так:

```js
load([...document.querySelectorAll('img')]);

function load(imgs) {
  let img = imgs.shift();
  imgs.length && (img.onload = img.onerror = load.bind(0, imgs));
  img.src = img.dataset.src;
}
```

```html
<img data-src="https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png"/>
<img data-src="https://i.imgur.com/tbmyMTo.jpg"/>
<img data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Mpe.jpg"/>
```